# Выборка из БД названий таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

В БД имеется несколько таблиц, их названия имеют такой формат:

```
dialog_login1_login2
dialog_login1_login3
dialog_login2_login3
dialog_login3_login1
```

Не совсем понимаю как мне составить sql запрос чтобы в результате он выдал например:

```
dialog_login1_login2
dialog_login1_login3
```

То есть выборка по фразе dialog_login1_*****

Либо такой результат:

```
dialog_login2_login3
```

То есть выборка по dialog_login2_*****

Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: `LIKE 'dialog_login1_%'` или `LIKE 'dialog_login2_%'`   не подходит?

Comment: По идее да, но не до конца понимаю мне через select делать запрос или как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно помочь

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  'dialog_login1_%'
```

Comment: show TABLEs LIKE 'dialog_1%'  Для себя нашёл такой ответ